# upstart: error while loading shared library

Tags: 16.04, login, upstart, systemd

I uninstalled json-c library on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
`# make uninstall`
and removed all rest json-c with

```
# find / -name "*json-c*" -exec rm -rf {} /;
```

after reboot, can not log into system - Log In loop

```
# cat ~/.xsession-error
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
/sbin/upstart: error while loading shared libraries: libjson-c.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried to reinstall json-c, it gives me a library named libjson-c.so.3 but not 2

and btw. system is under systemd, right?

```
# ps -e | grep systemd
1 ? 00:00:02 systemd
```

UPDATE: here is how i fixed broken package

```
# apt-get download libjson-c2
# dpkg -i libjson-c2
```

Comment: Previously asked [over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145084/ubuntu-16-04-log-in-loop).

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libjson-c2`?

Comment: You didn't ask a question, except whether Ubuntu 16.04 runs systemd, which is easily looked up. Do you still have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you needed this specific library?  I know many times people run into this issue is because they actually need libjson0, and sometimes they will get an ELFCLASS64 error and that is because they need the 32 bit version of the library instead of the 64 bit version.

For example :

```
sudo apt install libjson0:i386
```